# Where to put the FB.ui() function in java script while making a custom share button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a share button that alerts a nice and cool msg after sharing but no luck yet. FB documentation says that FB.ui() function must be included after FB.init() function. But the problem is when i do this it automatically pops up a window with fb share window but I want that it appears after the share button is clicked.

here is my code

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '1404714646487865',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.2'
});
FB.ui({
method:'share',
href:'http://umovietube.com/'
,},
function(response){if(response &&!response.error_code){
  alert('Posting completed.');}else{
  alert('Error while posting.');}});
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And here is the code I am using to display 
share button

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://umovietube.com" data-layout="box_count"></div>
```

I discovered that the FB.ui () function is in side the   window.fbAsyncInit = function(){} function just after FB.init() function.   which causes the unexpected popup window as soon as the page loads.
So where to put that FB.ui function to invoke and to get to  my desired action  from Facebook share button? I am using default share button code provided by Facebook that is quoted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is put the FB.ui() in a click handler.

E.g.

```
$('.share-button').click(function() { 
  FB.ui({
  method:'share',
  href:'http://umovietube.com/'
  ,},
  function(response){if(response &&!response.error_code){
    alert('Posting completed.');}else{
    alert('Error while posting.');}});
    };
  });
```

and then call this .share-button at the appropriate place via a class in the view.

Hope it helps!